# Copying the content of a list into a folder

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I have an arrayList "rules" containing Rules. Each Rule is an XML file and have some properties such as filename...

I want to copy the Rules from the arraylist to a folder named AllMRG. I tried the code between comments but I get the message "Source 'RG6.31.xml' does not exist".

I changed the code by the following, but there is still a problem with 'RG6.31.xml' and the folder AllMRG is empty even though the arrayList contains many Rules!

First attemption:

```
File AllMRGFolder = new File("AllMRG");
for(int p = 0; p < rules.size(); p++) {
    /* File MRGFile = new File(rules.get(p).fileName);  
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(MRGFile, AllMRGFolder);  */
        
    File MRGFile = new File("AllMRG/" + rules.get(p).fileName); 
    if (!MRGFile.exists()) {
        FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(MRGFile, AllMRGFolder);
    }
}
```

Second attemption:

```
String path = "AllMRG";
        for(Rule rule : rules) {
            File MRGFile = new File(rule.fileName);
            Files.copy(MRGFile.toPath(), (new File(path + MRGFile.getName())).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
```

PS: Rule is a class

```
public class Rule implements Comparable{

    public String fileName;
    public String matches;
    public String TPinstances;
    public int nbrOfMatches;
    public double T;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Rule){
            //processing to compare one Rule with another
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the entire code after having considered Shyam's answer. The same problem persists!

```
Path directoryPath = Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("AllMGR"));
        for(Rule rule : rules) {
            
            Path filePath = directoryPath.resolve(rule.fileName);
            Files.createFile(filePath);
     
            File MRGFile = new File(rule.fileName);
            String ruleContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(MRGFile.getPath())));
            String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(filePath));  
            fileContent=ruleContent;
            PrintWriter out13= new PrintWriter("AllMGR/"+rule.fileName+".xml");
            out13.print(fileContent);
            out13.close();
}
```

Comment: your code looks like correct. minor improvement: `File MRGFile = new File(AllMRGFolder, rules.get(p).fileName)`

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether your updated code works or you still need some help to fix it.

Comment: @Arvind I need to know if the updated code is correct

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi why to add AllMRGFolder?

Comment: Is `Rules` a class? If it is, did you write it? If you did then [edit] your question and post the code of that class. If you didn't write it then provide the API of that class, i.e. its "public" methods.

Comment: By the way, variable names should start with a lowercase letter by convention.

Comment: @Abra rules is an arraylist. Rule is a class that I wrote.

Comment: I assume that member `fileName` in class `Rule` contains a path to a file. If my assumption is correct, then does `fileName` contain an absolute path? Or does it contain a relative path? Or does it contain just a filename? An example of an absolute path (on Windows) is `C:\Users\George\data.xml`. An example of a relative path is `George\data.xml`. And an example of a filename is `George.xml`. So does member `fileName` in class `Rule` contain an absolute path, a relative path or just a filename?

Comment: fileName is a property of a rule. It represents just the name of the file corresponding to the rule: `rule.fileName = rgFile.getName();`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are creating a new `File` with `rule.filename` without giving any predefined path. Then, you are building a path like: `path + MRGFile.getName()` without any path delimiters and trying to copy the file to this location. I don't think this will work.

What can actually help you is, creating a base directory first and then creating individual files in it.

Create base directory:
`Path directoryPath = Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("AllMGRDir"));`

Then for each of your `Rule` object you can crate file using:

```
for(Rule rule : rules) {
      Path filePath = directoryPath.resolve(rule.fileName());
      Files.createFile(filePath);
// your remaining code
    }
```

The `resolve(String other)` method resolves the given path. Java doc says that:

> Converts a given path string to a `Path` and resolves it against this
> `Path` in exactly the manner specified by the `resolve(Path)` method.
> For example, suppose that the name separator is "/" and a path
> represents *"foo/bar"*, then invoking this method with the path string
> "gus" will result in the `Path` *"foo/bar/gus"*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean by "// you remaining code" that I need to add lines of code to finish the process of copying Rules to AllMRG directory?

Comment: Yes. The process that I've described, will just help you create files. You need to then add contents of `Rule` object in the way you want to those files when they are created.

Comment: I edited my question to add the remaining code... The same problem persists.

Comment: You have mistaken your `Rule` object to be a `File`. It is not. Once the file is created, you need to write the contents to it. You are trying to read and get content from an empty file.